# Byte swap question (Bitwise operation)

Tags: c

I have seen some bitwise operation practice questions (in C language) and there was one I didn't understand: you had to swap the nth and the mth byte in a specifc integer "x" using only bitwise operations, and that n and m were both <=3. The solution involved masking the last 8 bits of the number resulting from xor based on x >> (n<<3) to x >> (m<<3), but the part I don't understand is why they shifted m/n right 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if `n` is a position within the word, *in bytes*, then `8*n` is the same position *in bits*. And `n<<3` is the same as `8*n` (2<sup>3</sup> = 8).

With `n=1`, `n<<3` is `8`, and `(x >> (n << 3)) & 0xff` would move the second lowest byte to the bottom position, and mask the rest of the word out. (The bytes would numbered starting from zero, of course.)

<sub>(I'm assuming bytes of 8 bits, since I think that's by far the most common case at least nowadays.)</sub>